# Can't enter text fields into Xamarin projects

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, textfield

So I am just starting Xamarin and I finally got it set up and running. I started their tutorial for the Phoneword project and I hit a snag almost instantly. When I try to add any text fields my content/source section it goes blank except for a text box that says "the layout could not be loaded java.util.locale.tolanguagetag()ljava/lang/string;." The only thing it will let me do is close the file. If I save the changes then every time I open it I get the same error message. Any suggestions would help!

Comment: are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio?

Comment: It sounds like your layout might be invalid, can you post that (click on the source tab)?